# DateDiff NIGHTMARE

Tags: sql

seconfHere is an example:

```
ID       Datetime1            datetime2           (Results needed)
1        1/1/2010 7:54        1/2/2010 6:54            23
1        1/1/2010 7:54        1/4/2010 6:54            48
1        1/1/2010 7:54        1/5/2010 6:54            24   
2        1/5/2010 11:00       1/8/2010 11:00           72        
3        1/30/2010 23:05      2/1/2010 22:05           47
```

notice ID 1 in the first row it did a normal datediff but in the second and  third row I need it to use the `startdate` of datetime2 and `enddate` of datetime2 of thee same ID.

`turnaround time` column is what is the output column I need, I only tried normal datediff but it just calculates the difference between `datetime1` and `datetime2`. my problem is that it can be many IDs with a value of 1, so I need the datediff to dynamically update the `startdate` if another `enddate` exist for the same ID.
Im' working in a RDBMS 'Microsoft SQL server'
the code i tried is as followed:

select 
*
,datediff(hh,datetime1,datetime2) as 'Turnaround time'
 from
 my_table
  order by datetime1 asc
i hope this clears it out a little bit.
thank you in advance

Comment: Please give us an example of what you would like the outcome to be. Where did you do a datediff in that table, is the result of the datediff function in the turnaround column?

Comment: Can you show the actual code you tried please

Comment: What is your question? In the meantime, try something like this: `DateDiff(hour, MAX(datetime1, datetime2), MIN(datetim1, datetim2))`...

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: P.s. "I need it to use the startdate of datetime2 and enddate of datetime2". Eh? You want to diff the date with itself? That doesn't sound right. Datetime2 is a single value, not separate start and end values. Can you clarify what this statement means, and what you expect the result to be?

Comment: @ADyson I think OP mean for rows with same ID, so time between first and second `datetime2` for ID = 1 for instance

Comment: the turnaround time column is what is the output column i need, i only tried normal datediff but that just calculates the differenece between datetime1 and datetime2. my problem is that it can be many IDs with a value of 1, so i need the datediff to dynamically change the start date if another enddate exist for the same ID.

Comment: Thanks, but please use the "edit" button to add this information (and the other information people have requested in earlier comments) to the main question. If you bury important detail in this big list of comments people might not see it, and they might vote to close your question, or give downvotes, or just not understand and therefore not give an answer

Comment: Again thanks but please also review the earlier comments and supply requested info e.g. your DBMS, any code attempts so far, etc.

Comment: Also, how is the code supposed to know in what order the rows which have the same ID should be arranged, so as to know the "previous" row? Is there another column in the table which would indicate this? Perhaps an auto-increment primary key ID, or a "date created" / timestamp column, or some other field indicating the sequence

Answer (score 0):

the answer was  Lead and Lag functions URL below: 
https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html